# convergence of complex series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For what values ​​of $(a,b\in \mathbb{C})$ does this series converge or diverge?

$\sum\frac{(k-a)^2}{(k-b)^3}$

if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ by the Limit comparison test (with $\sum\frac{1}{k}$ ) I know that the series diverges but if $(a,b\in \mathbb{C})$ I do not know how to continue.

Comment: I believe this diverges for $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ by the Comparison Test as well...

Answer (score 1):

We have to assume that $b$ is not a negative integer. Write $$(k-a)^2=(k-b+\color{red}{b-a})^2=(k-b)^2+2(k-b)\color{red}{(b-a)}+\color{red}{(b-a)^2}.$$
As the series $\sum_k\frac 1{(k-b)^p}$, where $p=2$ or $p=3$ are convergent, the problems reduces to the convergence of $\sum_k\frac 1{k-b}$, which doesn't take place, since $\sum_k\frac 1{k-b}-\frac 1k$ is convergent.